code for inverted pendulum project. What am I doing wrong?
I want to project an inverted pendulum, the hardware is in the image.I've written the next code , but it doesn't work, the vibrations from the motors interfere with the accelerometer(ADXL345) too much and it can't stand on its own. What am I doing wrong? Could someone provide some support after reviewing the code? Would a MPU6050 gyroscope attached to it improve the situation? The MCU is an Raspberry Pi Pico enter image description here
from machine import Pin, I2C, PWM
import time
import ustruct
import math


ADXL345_ADDRESS = 0x53
ADXL345_POWER_CTL = 0x2D
ADXL345_DATA_FORMAT = 0x31
ADXL345_DATAX0 = 0x32


i2c = I2C(1, sda=Pin(2), scl=Pin(3))


pwm_forward = PWM(Pin(11, Pin.OUT))
pwm_backward = PWM(Pin(12, Pin.OUT))
pwm_forward.freq(1000)
pwm_backward.freq(1000)

def init_adxl345():
    i2c.writeto_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_POWER_CTL, b'\x08') 
    i2c.writeto_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_DATA_FORMAT, b'\x08') 


alpha = 0.5
last_z = 0

def read_accel_data():
    global last_z
    data = i2c.readfrom_mem(ADXL345_ADDRESS, ADXL345_DATAX0, 6)
    x, y, z = ustruct.unpack('<3h', data)
    # Aplicarea filtrului low-pass
    filtered_z = alpha * z + (1 - alpha) * last_z
    last_z = filtered_z
    return x, y, filtered_z

def calculate_angle(z):

    g = 9.81
    z_scaled = z * g / 256
    angle = math.asin(min(max(z_scaled / g, -1), 1))  
    return angle

init_adxl345()

class PID:
    def __init__(self, kp, ki, kd, dead_zone=0.00001):
        self.kp = kp
        self.ki = ki
        self.kd = kd
        self.dead_zone = dead_zone
        self.setpoint = 0
        self.last_error = 0
        self.integral = 0

    def update(self, current_value, dt):
        error = self.setpoint - current_value
        if abs(error) < self.dead_zone:
            error = 0 
        self.integral += error * dt
        derivative = (error - self.last_error) / dt if dt > 0 else 0
        self.last_error = error
        output = (self.kp * error) + (self.ki * self.integral) + (self.kd * derivative)
        return output

pid_controller = PID(kp=10, ki=5, kd=1)

while True:
    start_time = time.ticks_ms()
    x, y, z = read_accel_data()
    angle = calculate_angle(z)
    pid_output = pid_controller.update(angle, 0.02)


    if pid_output > 0:
        pwm_value = min(int(abs(pid_output) * 1000), 65535) 
        pwm_forward.duty_u16(pwm_value)
        pwm_backward.duty_u16(0)
    elif pid_output < 0:
        pwm_value = min(int(abs(pid_output) * 1000), 65535)
        pwm_forward.duty_u16(0)
        pwm_backward.duty_u16(pwm_value)

    #print(f"Angle: {math.degrees(angle):.2f} degrees, PID output: {pid_output:.2f}")
    time.sleep(max(0, 0.05 - (time.ticks_ms() - start_time) / 1000))


I've tried to modify the parameters of the PID, but it still didn't work

I presume you are actually trying to make a physical pendulum stay upright with this code. You have to match the driver frequency to the physical resonance of the pendulum to get it to want to stay upright on its own. A simple low pass filter on the accelerometer output may help so that it doesn't see sharp impulses from your motor but does see the slower pendulum movement. It could also just be a matter of tuning the drive frequency closer to resonance to make it work. Putting a hoop around the thing to keep it fairly close to vertical makes this easier to do in practice.
